# Prints a lot of [object Object] in list instead of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

Here is my code on jquery.

When i input some text, the only display is `[object Object]`, but when i `console.log(areaname)` the result is ok.

Already stringify the data but the result is not ok

```js
$('#arealist').btsListFilter('#searcharea', {

  sourceTmpl: '<a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost:3000/legone/survey/surveyform/households"><span>' + {
    areaname
  } + '</span></a>',
  sourceData: function(text, callback) {
    var data = {};

    data.areaname = $('#searcharea').val();
    console.log(areaname + "areaname");

    /*$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/legone/survey/dblookup/listareas", {provcode:province,keyword:keyword},
       function ( jsonData )
       {
          callback(jsonData);
       } );*/
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/legone/survey/dblookup/listareas',
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data[0].areaname);
        areaname = data.areaname;
        callback(data);
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mind formatting your code so I can more easily help you?

Comment: What do you mean by formatting my code? sorry im just new

Comment: Compare [your original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41995937/1) to the current post that someone edited. Do you not see a difference?

Comment: the post is already edited

Comment: By the way i have a global variable areaname...

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by `When i input some text,` I don't see any inputs? You need to include the larger context, or better explain your question!

Comment: `{ areaname }` is *(in that context)* a shorthand for `{ areaname: areaname }`, wich is an object. And concatenating a string *(like `'<a class=...`)* and an object converts the object into a string first, wich usually is `"[object Object]"`, unless there is a `toString()` or `valueOf()`method involved.

Comment: Im sorry, what i mean is when i input a text in the textbox(searcharea), the inputted data will search in the database(areaname) if there were matches in the text i inputted. But it will only display [object Object] instead of areaname(if matched), i tried checking in console.log and it displays the output that i want(areaname text), i hope u understand my question

Comment: @Thomas can you answer it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the `[object Object]` is because you're printing an object.

#### if `areaname` is not an object

In your code you have:

```
sourceTmpl: '<a class="list-group-item" href="..."><span>' + {
  areaname
} + '</span></a>',
```

The brackets wrapping the variable `{areaname}` creates an object, which you are printing

#### if `areaname` is an object (and the brackets is for the external library)

What you want to do is print separate keys of the object example:

```
// example content of areaname object
// areaname = {
//   foo = "obi_1",
//   bar = "kenobi"
// }

// Thus
sourceTmpl: '<a class="list-group-item" href="..."><span>'
  + areaname.foo + ' ' + areaname.bar
  + '</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following snippet:

```
var jsonObj=JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log("data:"+jsonObj);
```